# OpenWRT: Redirect traffic for single clients to different gateway

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, openwrt

I am currently reversing a wifi toy. To analyse the devices protocol I would like to redirect its traffic to a linux machine (kali). Then I am using sslsplit to peek into the ssl traffic (CA.cert is replaced on the toy).

iptables rule on the kali machine:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 844
```

The kali machine uses a different gateway to access the web.

I would prefer a solution based on OpenWRTs GUI.

**How to redirect the traffic for a single ip source to a different gateway?**